# Исключающее ИЛИ на Глаголе

Tags: битовые-операции

Объясните, пожалуйста, кто знает, как реализовать операцию побитового исключающего ИЛИ для целых переменных на языке Глагол? Где-то слышал, что это делается при помощи отдела ОБХОД, а вот как - не знаю.

Comment: Ох мамочка… Это где это и кто же Вам такому языку обучает?

Comment: тоже первый раз о таком слышу. Первая мысль что это опечатка, а на самом деле алгол

Comment: Это Oberon пропущенный через ПРОМТ. Кто-то из патриотов перевёл =).

Comment: Да не совсем через ПРОМТ. Служебные слова подбирались к каждой сущности исходя из её смысла, а не принятого аналогичного слова в языках программирования, основанных на английском языке. Действительно, это диалект Оберона с русскими служебными словами. А обучаемся мы ему сами, и, могу сказать, имея опыт программирования на ЯП с английской основой, что учиться этому языку намного легче (особенно человеку, изначально не знающему английский язык), да и читаемость кода выше.

Comment: Что касается собственно вопроса: видимо, нужно использовать преобразование видов данных при помощи отдела ОБХОД, после чего производить над ними операции. Но только какие какое преобразование и какие операции?

Comment: Может быть вы и правы. Я учился на традиционных англ. языках и русский текст в коде очень сильно режет глаз. А ещё учитывая что все терминология вся английская -- смысла мало. Впрочем это всё оффтоп.

Comment: Я поддерживаю @Vladimir VG. Боюсь, долго придётся искать человека, который сможет помочь с ОТДЕЛАМИ (мне страшно представить, какую сущность в языке программирования можно было назвать таким словом). :(

Comment: В советское время были десятки языков программирования, основанных  на русском. От автокодов (ассемблеров) отечественных ЭВМ до специализированных языков, применявшихся в программировании космических аппаратов. Была и терминология своя. Просто сейчас уже позабыли это всё. А зря.
А про отдел - элементарно. Это модуль, он же подпрограмма.

Comment: А про отдел - элементарно. Это модуль, он же подпрограмма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл сам.

```
ЗАДАЧА ИсклИЛИ(ч1, ч2: ЦЕЛ): ЦЕЛ; 
УКАЗ 
  ВОЗВРАТ ОБХОД.Значение(ЦЕЛ, ОБХОД.Значение(МНОЖ, ч1) / ОБХОД.Значение(МНОЖ, ч2)) 
КОН ИсклИЛИ;
```

Симметрическая разность множеств в отношении двоичных разрядов реализует как раз исключающее ИЛИ.